# Returning Textbox text to the last good value from Settings

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a CheckBox and a WrapPanel in a Grid. The WrapPanel has two TextBox's inside of it. When the CheckBox is checked the whole WrapPanel is disabled. The TextBox's are bound to Properties.Settings.Default properties. The TextBox's also use ValidationRule's to validate the input.

What I would like to do: If one or both of the TextBox's have a validation error, I would like the act of checking the CheckBox to return the TextBox's text to the last good value from the Settings.Default property and thus clear the error.

I don't really care about sticking to some strict MVVM model anymore (this window is small and doesn't even have a ViewModel. What's the simplest way of achieving what I want?

I think I'm on the right path by adding an event handler to the Checked property of the CheckBox, but it is throwing NullReference as soon as I open the window, I don't yet have a reference to minBox and maxBox when the event handler is attached, I think.

```
    private void AllPages_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        minBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
        maxBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
    }
```

;

```
           <CheckBox Name="AllPages" Margin ="10,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Content="All Pages"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.AllPages, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <WrapPanel Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" 
                       IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=AllPages, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource boolConvert}, Mode=OneWay}">
                <TextBox Name="minBox" MaxWidth="30" MinWidth="30" MaxLength="3">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Settings}" Path="Default.MinPage" Mode="TwoWay"
                                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <local:MinValidationRule/>
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
                <Label Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Content="to"/>
                <TextBox Name="maxBox" MaxWidth="30" MinWidth="30" MaxLength="3">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Settings}" Path="Default.MaxPage" Mode="TwoWay"
                                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <local:MaxValidationRule/>
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
            </WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
    private void AllPages_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (minBox != null) minBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
        if (maxBox != null) maxBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
    }
```